# How to include a trait in tests\unit scripts from an app\command script?

Tags: php, laravel

Using Laravel 5.5 I've created a series of unit tests that test all of my route end points. I also created a command line script that compares the application's actual routes to the list of routes tested by the unit tests.  This worked fine until I added a trait to many of the unit tests to facilitate them.  Now my command line script is won't run, complaining, *Cannot instantiate trait Tests\Unit\DataTrait*

I've tried a variety of require, require_once but my command line script just won't run.

Here is a snippet from one of the unit tests:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/BaseRouteTest.php');

use \App\User;
use Tests\Unit\DataTrait;

class UserRoutesTest extends BaseRouteTest
{
  use DataTrait;
```

Comment: Aren't you already in the Tests\Unit namespace. Seems like it's trying to instantiate Tests\Unit\Tests\Unit\DataTrait. If not that can you give an example of where you use the code from DataTrait?

Comment: The script I use to check the routes isn't in \Tests\Unit, but \App\Console\Commands. The unit tests test the actual routes, my console command merely does an inventory, cross checking which routes have tests. Thanks for your response!

Comment: I've tried re-creating a similar situation locally but cannot to break the program in the same way as yours. Without exposing more code or insight on how your project is configured I'm afraid I can't guess what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Well duh on me.  What I failed to point out in my example - cuz it just didn't occur to me was I was using a directory scan to get my classes - and of course the trait script was getting pulled in with all the other classes.